# Angular attributes Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

I have this in my parent component:

```
target: {
  garageName: string,
  details: string
}
```

So its basically like define an interface.

I have in my HTML

```
<div>
  <input 
    (change)="inputChange($event)" 
    placeholder='add garagename'>
</div>
```

my parent.ts file:

```
inputChange(event){
  this.target.garageName = event.target.value;
}
```

and I keep getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'garageName' of undefined
>           at eval (eval at

Why this happend? I know its undefined, because i want to put value in it. and not an initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't initialized the `target` yet.

Do that and it should work just fine. Something like this:

```
target: { garageName: string, details: string } = {
  garageName: '',
  details: ''
};

...

inputChange(event) {
  this.target.garageName = event.target.value;
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/update-angular-input-on-blur?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable and you should be good. Like below:

```
target: { garageName: string, details: string } = { garageName:'', details:''};
```